# HTML elements gets distorted after including bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am a learning HTML/CSS. I have made two simple circles and a rotating element in between. Afterwards, I decided to use bootstrap for decorating subsequent elements. However, as soon as I include the link to bootstrap, the circles get distorted and the animation is ruined.

Also, if I remove the statement overflow: hidden, on re-sizing the browser, the scroll bar starts to behave erratically. If I let it be, I am not able to insert further content down the window.

Please help!

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5">
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0%;
    }
    
    body {
      background-color: #080808;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    #spinner,
    #spinner:before,
    #spinner:after {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      background: none;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 5px solid cyan;
    }
    
    #spinner {
      height: 386px;
      width: 386px;
      margin: -208px;
      border: 15px solid blue;
      z-index: 1;
      border-top: 15px solid red;
      -webkit-animation: spin 1s ease-in-out infinite;
      -moz-animation: spin 1s ease-in-out infinite;
      -ms-animation: spin 1s ease-in-out infinite;
      -o-animation: spin 1s ease-in-out infinite;
      animation: spin 1s ease-in-out infinite;
    }
    
    #spinner:before {
      content: "";
      height: 372px;
      width: 372px;
      margin: -191px;
    }
    
    #spinner:after {
      content: "";
      width: 420px;
      height: 420px;
      margin: -215px;
    }
    
    #vline,
    #hline,
    #dline1,
    #dline2 {
      height: 420px;
      position: absolute;
      border-left: 1px solid cyan;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-top: -210px;
    }
    
    #hline {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
      transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    
    #dline1 {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
      transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    
    #dline2 {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
    
    @keyframes "spin" {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
    
    @-moz-keyframes spin {
      0% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes "spin" {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
    
    @-ms-keyframes "spin" {
      0% {
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
    
    @-o-keyframes "spin" {
      0% {
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
  </style>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="spinner"></div>
  <div id="vline"></div>
  <div id="hline"></div>
  <div id="dline1"></div>
  <div id="dline2"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you might want to add bootstrap links you were trying to add.

Comment: It is there. I have commented it out for demonstrating the original code. Including it distorts the elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap sets `box-sizing: border-box;` on everything.
Set `box-sizing: content-box;` on elements and pseudo-elements in your spinner:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.spinner-container *,
.spinner-container :after,
.spinner-container :before {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0%;
}

body {
  background-color: #080808!important;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#spinner,
#spinner:before,
#spinner:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid cyan;
}

#spinner {
  height: 386px;
  width: 386px;
  margin: -208px;
  border: 15px solid blue;
  z-index: 1;
  border-top: 15px solid red;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1s ease-in-out infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin 1s ease-in-out infinite;
  -ms-animation: spin 1s ease-in-out infinite;
  -o-animation: spin 1s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: spin 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

#spinner:before {
  content: "";
  height: 372px;
  width: 372px;
  margin: -191px;
}

#spinner:after {
  content: "";
  width: 420px;
  height: 420px;
  margin: -215px;
}

#vline,
#hline,
#dline1,
#dline2 {
  height: 420px;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 1px solid cyan;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -210px;
}

#hline {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#dline1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#dline2 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

@keyframes "spin" {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes "spin" {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes "spin" {
  0% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes "spin" {
  0% {
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="spinner-container">
  <div id="spinner"></div>
  <div id="vline"></div>
  <div id="hline"></div>
  <div id="dline1"></div>
  <div id="dline2"></div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** Scrollbar appears erratic because your `#spinner` pushes `body` out while spinning. To solve this problem put everything in container, set container's width and height, position it in the center and set `overflow:hidden;` on it. Also, mind media-queries for cases when display is smaller than spinner:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.spinner-container *,
.spinner-container :after,
.spinner-container :before {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.spinner-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 430px;
    width: 430px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

@media (max-height: 430px) {
  .spinner-container {
    transform: translate(-50%,0);
    top: 0;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 430px) {
  .spinner-container {
    transform: translate(0,-50%);
    left: 0;
  }
}
@media (max-height:430px) and (max-width: 430px) {
  .spinner-container {
    transform: none;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0%;
}

body {
  background-color: #080808!important;
}

#spinner,
#spinner:before,
#spinner:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid cyan;
}

#spinner {
  height: 386px;
  width: 386px;
  margin: -208px;
  border: 15px solid blue;
  z-index: 1;
  border-top: 15px solid red;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1s ease-in-out infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin 1s ease-in-out infinite;
  -ms-animation: spin 1s ease-in-out infinite;
  -o-animation: spin 1s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: spin 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

#spinner:before {
  content: "";
  height: 372px;
  width: 372px;
  margin: -191px;
}

#spinner:after {
  content: "";
  width: 420px;
  height: 420px;
  margin: -215px;
}

#vline,
#hline,
#dline1,
#dline2 {
  height: 420px;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 1px solid cyan;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -210px;
}

#hline {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#dline1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#dline2 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

@keyframes "spin" {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes "spin" {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes "spin" {
  0% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes "spin" {
  0% {
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="spinner-container">
  <div id="spinner"></div>
  <div id="vline"></div>
  <div id="hline"></div>
  <div id="dline1"></div>
  <div id="dline2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works fine. Now, the html elements are rendered just fine. :)
Can you also help me out with a solution to the overflow:hidden thing?

Comment: @Enqueue Edited my answer